# Checking to see if user has entered a correct filesystem path

Tags: c#

I'm creating a small C# program that reads a textile from a 'user chosen' location..  I've managed to read the files correctly, but I would like to display an error message to the user if they type the filename/path incorrectly.... or if the file type is incorrect. 
I've tried everything within my limited knowledge and now i'm a little stuck.  Any help at all would be very much appreciated. Thanks

```
using System;

class ReadFromFile
{
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Welcome to Decrypter (Press any key to               begin)");
    Console.ReadKey ();

    //User selects file they wish to decrypt
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    string path;


    Console.WriteLine ("\nPlease type the path to your file");
    path = Console.ReadLine ();

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    System.IO.StreamReader file = 
        new System.IO.StreamReader (path);

      while ((line = file.ReadLine ()) != null) {

            Console.WriteLine (line);
            counter++;
        }

        file.Close ();

        // Suspend the screen.
        Console.ReadLine ();
        }
        }
```

Comment: If you just want to see if the path is valid and the file exists you could use [`File.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
try
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        // Tell the user
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // tell the user
}
```

for file existence

Add

```
using System.IO;
```

to top of code file

Comment: Althoug it might be useful to use `Try...Catch` if you are using IO-methods it looks like they were important in this case. But that's not the case. Actually `File.Exists` works without a problem if the path is invalid.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, you're right, it's probably overkill since it appears that `File.Exists` doesn't throw exceptions even when `path` is null or otherwise invalid or the file is otherwise inaccessible.

Comment: would be a strange method that checks if you provide a valid path but throws an exception if that validation returned `false`. What's the purpose of the `bool` return value then?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, well I was thinking of the case of `null` path or invalid characters, etc. But after reading the docs, it indicates `false` is returned in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
bool exists = System.IO.File.Exists(path);
```